# VS is drunk, it compiles my project correctly, but I still have some unresolved symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I think my VS is drunk (2010 & 2012).

**The symptoms**

I open a particular project and I see some unresolved symbols. However, when I compile the project it builds succesfull and I can run it. in 2010 I can click on the unresolved symbols and it brings me to their declaration and implementation pages. (not in 2012) My intellisence also doesn't work on the symbols that are unresolved, it does work for all the rest.

I tried restarting VS, but to no avail.

I don't think adding more references is the answer, since the projects compiles and runs ok.

**Extra info:** I use Rescharper

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem from time to time too

Are you working with resharper?

=> delete '_ReSharper.[ProjectName]' file and restart VisualStudio

Comment: @demian: your welcome. my first activity when I get strange behaviour in visual studio is deleting this file ;-)

Comment: Ah, but only temporary, when it recreates the file, it does it again.

Comment: and you can reproduce this behaviour repeated by deleting the resharper file?

Comment: Yes I can. with both VS versions

Comment: I remember that I had this problem long time ago when I worked with Accessor-Classes for access private fields/methods in unittests